# How do you change fish pwd length in prompt using fish_prompt_pwd_dir_length?

Tags: shell, fish

I want fish shell to show full path in prompt. Looking at [source](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/blob/master/share/functions/prompt_pwd.fish) of pwd_prompt I see a variable named fish_prompt_pwd_dir_length, that should do what I want if I set it to 0.

But when I do `set -U fish_prompt_pwd_dir_length 0` nothing happens.

Looking in `fish_config` variables tab I see that this var is set to 0, but still path shown reduced.

What am I doing wrong and can you actually do that without writing your own pwd_prompt function?

Comment: Are you using fish from git? That change went in [about 3 weeks ago](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/commit/09bd938e252fd983fb93a50e5c177b4a41642ce0). If you are not it won't work, and the newer prompt_pwd.fish relies on the `string` builtin which means it won't work with an older (read: released) fish.

Comment: I’m new to fish and installed it yesterday with brew. And you answered to all my questions (including one about string, that didn’t work when I tried to create version of prompt by myself), thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPD (June 20, 2016):**

Since version 2.3.0 (which is now recent) all is working as expected

**Previous answer:**

My workaround so far is to copy `prompt_pwd` into new function `prompt_pwd_full` and mess with it a little bit.

prompt_pwd_full.fish:

```
set -l args_pre
set args_pre $args_pre -e 's|^/private/|/|'

function prompt_pwd_full -V args_pre
  set -q fish_prompt_pwd_dir_length; or set -l fish_prompt_pwd_dir_length 1

  if [ $fish_prompt_pwd_dir_length -eq 0 ]
    set -l fish_prompt_pwd_dir_length 99999
  end

  set -l realhome ~
  echo $PWD | sed -e "s|^$realhome|~|" $args_pre -e 's-\([^/.]{'"$fish_prompt_pwd_dir_length"'}\)[^/]*/-\1/-g'
end
```

note: I am on OS X, so I threw out a bunch of code that wasn’t related to it, so it might not work in other OS’es.

**UPD:**
As [faho](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33714385/how-do-you-change-fish-pwd-length-in-prompt-using-fish-prompt-pwd-dir-length/33721414#comment55238117_33721414) noted in the comment, there is no particular reason to rewrite `/private/` to `/`, so my function is looking like this now:

```
function prompt_pwd_full
  set -q fish_prompt_pwd_dir_length; or set -l fish_prompt_pwd_dir_length 1

  if [ $fish_prompt_pwd_dir_length -eq 0 ]
    set -l fish_prompt_pwd_dir_length 99999
  end

  set -l realhome ~
  echo $PWD | sed -e "s|^$realhome|~|" -e 's-\([^/.]{'"$fish_prompt_pwd_dir_length"'}\)[^/]*/-\1/-g'
end
```

Comment: Looks good - btw, we've removed the args_pre stuff since there's no particular reason to make /private special.

Comment: On my system, I had to patch to use extended-regexp : `echo $PWD | sed -e "s|^$realhome|~|" -re 's-([^/.]{'"$fish_prompt_pwd_dir_length"'})[^/]*/-\1/-g'`

Answer (score 3):

Adding `set -g fish_prompt_pwd_dir_length 80` to `~/.config/fish/config.fish` works for me. My fish version is 3.0.2